# Enter Opposite Position How?

Tags: pine-script

Hi all I'm new to pinescript. I preapered a strategy that based on DEMA Fast and Slow crosses. I want to send 4 seperated massege to bot. I think this is what I want: [Bot Sample](https://docs.wunderbit.co/traders/bots/bot-sample-code?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=free_test_bot_for_tradingview&utm_term=2021-07-14). I want to modify my strategy code like that but couldn't success. This my Strategy code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © cryptoseruveni

//@version=4
strategy("DEMA Cross Strategy", "DEMA Cross", overlay=true, currency="USD", default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

tradeDirection = input(title="Trade Direction", defval="Both", options=["Long", "Short", "Both"])

atrShow = input(title="ATR On/Off", type=input.bool, defval=false, inline = "ATRSettings")
atrDays = input(7, "- Length", inline = "ATRSettings")
atrColor = input(title="Color", type=input.color, defval=#ffae42, inline = "ATRSettings")

DemaLengthFast = input(7, title="Fast DEMA", minval=1, type=input.integer, group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "FastSettings")
FastSource   = input(defval = close, title = "Source", group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "FastSettings")
FastColor = input(title="Color", type=input.color, defval=#cf20a8, group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "FastSettings")

DemaLengthSlow = input(30, title="Slow DEMA", minval=1, type=input.integer, group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "SlowSettings")
SlowSource   = input(defval = close, title = "Source", group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "SlowSettings")
SlowColor = input(title="Color", type=input.color, defval=#1b96cb, group = "DEMA Settings", inline = "SlowSettings")

useStartPeriodTime = input(true, "Start", input.bool, group = "Date Settings", inline = "Start Period")
startPeriodTime = input(timestamp("01 Jan 2020"), "", input.time, group = "Date Settings", inline = "Start Period")

useEndPeriodTime = input(true, "End", input.bool, group = "Date Settings", inline = "End Period")
endPeriodTime = input(timestamp("01 June 2022"), "", input.time, group = "Date Settings", inline = "End Period")

inDateRange = (time >= startPeriodTime) and (time < endPeriodTime)
longOK  = (tradeDirection == "Long") or (tradeDirection == "Both")
shortOK = (tradeDirection == "Short") or (tradeDirection == "Both")

ef1 = ema(FastSource, DemaLengthFast)
ef2 = ema(ef1, DemaLengthFast)
DemaFast = 2 * ef1 - ef2

es1 = ema(SlowSource, DemaLengthSlow)
es2 = ema(es1, DemaLengthSlow)
DemaSlow = 2 * es1 - es2

FastPlot = plot(DemaFast, color = FastColor , title="DEMA Fast", linewidth=2)
SlowPlot = plot(DemaSlow, color = SlowColor , title="DEMA Slow", linewidth=2)

fillcolor = DemaFast > DemaSlow ? SlowColor : FastColor
fill(FastPlot, SlowPlot, color=fillcolor)

theAtr = atr(atrDays)
plot(atrShow ? theAtr:na, title="ATR", linewidth=2, color = atrColor)

enterLong = crossover(DemaFast, DemaSlow)
enterShort = crossunder(DemaFast, DemaSlow)


if (inDateRange)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment = "Long Comment", when = enterLong and longOK)
    strategy.close("long", when=enterShort, comment = "Long Exit Comment", qty_percent = 100)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment = "Short Comment", when = enterShort and shortOK)
    strategy.close("short", when=enterLong, comment = "Short Exit Comment", qty_percent = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply your strategy on the chart, create the alert for it and type `{{strategy.order.comment}}` in the alert message control.